# C++ homework, cant get the right output for my program

Tags: char, integer, cin

```
// Nate Banks
// Homework 2
// 10/25/2022

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char name;
    int birth;
    int year = 2022;

    cout << "Please enter your name and year of birth:";
    cin >> name >> birth;

    

    cout << "Hi " << name << "!" << " You are " << year - birth << " years old!";

    return 0;
}
```

What im expecting to happen is that it displays the message HI input name! you are (however old) years old!

but what really happens is: Please enter you r name and year of birth: Nate 2003

Hi N! you are 2022 years old!

Im new to c++ so I just need a quick simple fix nothing to spiffy thanks!

Comment: `char foo` can only hold 1 single letter.  `std::string foo` can hold a full name. `char foo[60]` can hold 59 letters + an end of string marker, but `std::string` is easier and safer to work with because if you copy 70 characters into a 60-character `char` array, things go Horribly Wrong.